# Kafka: Using request/response patterns in a Kafka-driven architecture

Tags: apache-kafka

I work at a small company trying to modernize our data-exchange and IPC for our systems. One improvements that has been eagerly discussed with our team is the implementation of Kafka as a way to link our distributed servers and more reliably pass data between processes. Previously, this had been a gnarled mess of sockets interlacing our programs.

The system my company develops is has a lot of real-time data capture, so the event streaming of Kafka makes perfect sense for distributing all of the real-time data. However, there are places in which a *synchronous* request-response type query would need to be made (ex. a webpage might ask "what are the settings for this script?")

I have found a couple of answers here on StackOverflow about how Kafka can be mangled into a request/response format, using request topics and response topics and such, but the whole process seems a bit *square-peg-round-hole* and I was wondering how other companies accomplish both their event-streaming goals and their synchronous request-response goals.

Is a comprehensive solution to have both a Kafka cluster and a RESTful API side by side? Is using Kafka in a request-response manner something that is done at a professional level?

Any input would be tremendously valuable, thank you.

Comment: The answer isn't specific to Kafka. You'd need to be okay with eventually consistent data-access patterns if you plan on using any messaging system, and have said system dump records into some persistence layer than an API can query

Comment: Assuming you did want a Kafka-specific solution, you can look at "Interactive Queries" feature of _Kafka Streams_, which allows you to more easily build RPC/API layer over streaming events

Comment: Example of above https://www.azkarrastreams.io/docs/getting-started/